# displaying data returned through ajax as link

Tags: php, html, jquery

i am passing an "id" and "data" through ajax to php .Here is the jquery ajax code

```
1.$.ajax({//Make the Ajax Request
2.           type: "POST",
3.                url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
4.                data:datastr,
5.                success: function(arrayphp)
6.               {
7.                   //here iam displaying the returned data.
8.                   //I wanna display this data as link
9.                   //because on clicking on it I 
10.                  //again want to call another php script.
11.                 $(".searchby .searchlist").append(arrayphp); 
12.                            
13.                }
14.            });

15. I have not shown the php code.The code is working well.
16.BUT iam unable to display the data as link.I also want to give the data a "class name".
17.PLEASE if anybody know ...fix this problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data returned by the php is just the label of the link you may use the following code:

```
$.ajax({//Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
    data:datastr,
    success: function(arrayphp)
    {
        var link = $('<a href="#" class="my-class">' + arrayphp + '</a>');
        $(".searchby .searchlist").append(link); 

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother...I was stucked on this problem for three days.Your code is working..

Comment: You are welcome. (You may mark my answer as correct, so anybody else could use it as well).

Comment: @ krasimir look below i have some query related to it

Comment: What if you do this directly into javascript. Is the class coming from the php.

Comment: @ krasimir how to access the class of the link from outside of the ajax function

Comment: You may try the following:
var classOfThelink = link.attr("class");